# How can i change default shipping address

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping-address

How can i change the default shipping address of a current user programmatically.

Comment: Are you want to create a new address and set that one as default?

Comment: No. I am having three address A,B and C where C is set as default. Now i want to set Default shipping address to A. How can i do it?

Comment: Check my answer, I hope it will work.

Comment: if my answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark, hit that tickmark for right answer that will help future readers.

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/set-default-shipping-address-of-customer-magento-2/ set default shipping address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$YourAddressId = 1; //Your address id which you want to set as default;

$address = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Address')->load($YourAddressId);

$address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
$address->setIsDefaultShipping('1');

try{
        $address->save();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
        Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Your method is right but will it be for a current user ? This could change other users address.

Comment: Or we can search that address present for the current user if yes then change. what you think?

Comment: @avesh I have update my answer. you can pass customer id which you want to update. by $address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())

Comment: setIsDefaultBilling() method is not part of the Magento\Customer\Model\Address

Comment: What error you got ?

Comment: I am not getting any error, neither it is changing the default address. My Editor suggesting that $address doesn't have setIsDefaultBilling() method.

Comment: Ya it's working. It would been better if we use dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not good practice because we should never reference the
`objectManager` class directly (except on few exceptions stated [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html)) The "correct"  solution is to use constructor dependency injection as shown below within a class:

```
    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
    */
    private $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var AddressRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $addressRepository;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
    */
    private $logger

   
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,'
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger

    ) {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

/* then somewhere within your class put this logic*/
try {
      //N.B you must define $addressId and $customerId somewhere in your logic
        $address = $this->addressRepository->getById($addressId)->setCustomerId($customerId);
        $address->setIsDefaultShipping(true);

        $this->addressRepository->save($address);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($exception);
    }
```